# How can I discover SMB File Servers on the local network in macOS?

Tags: macos, networking, filesystems, bonjour, upnp

I need to list all available SMB hosts with their network addresses on the local network on a Mac. Any method works (BSD API, (Core)Foundation API or shell command).

#### Details

When using the macOS Finder, Go -> Network (shift-cmd-K), it is able to list systems running Windows or Linux that share volumes via **smb**. This proves that the servers are discoverable somehow.

I've tried to see if the servers are advertised over Bonjour or SSDP, but that's not the case.

How does Apple's code find them and how can I do this, too?

Does Windows/SMB perhaps use yet-another service announcement protocol for this? If so, what is it?

Comment: To anybody voting to close as “This question currently includes multiple questions in one”: Please post a comment elaborating on what you think those separate questions are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could it be WINS or some Microsoft proprietary stuff?

Ok, I've researched a bit more: this is done via NetBIOS. If you check out this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/160396/listing-available-smb-shares-on-a-network-through-the-command-line-in-linux) it'll use `nmblookup __SAMBA__`, which is something you can also do on macOS via `smbutil view //__SAMBA__`.

So you may need to find a NetBIOS library to do the lookup from within your app.

---

Edit: Further investigation shows that it's indeed the WINS protocol that's used here. `nmblookup` performs an UDP broadcast, which I've captured with Wireshark (in this case via `nmblookup WORKGROUP`, which in my setup returns the same information as `nmblookup "*"`):

[image: Wireshark screenshot of the UDP request showing the]

The answers come in one after the other and their UDP packets contain the IP-Addressed in their last for bytes:

[image]

I've tried creating an example Python script that opens an UDP socket and sends the request, but receiving turned out to be a bit more difficult.

---

Another update: I've found a UDP broadcast example and adapted it a WINS request: [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/karstenBriksoft/459d678b7716a8f8e9bb1cb7ce211375).

Basically you create a socket via `socket()`, enable broadcasts via `setsockopt()` and then you send the packet via `sendto()`.

To read the various responses, use `select()` and `recvfrom()` multiple times. Provide a reasonable timeout to not wait indefinitely, in case no further responses have been received.

Sockets are weird API for sure.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more implementation details

Comment: `nmblookup` is part of `samba`

Comment: I‘m not saying you should call these tools. I think you can install them for debugging purposes but doing an UDP Request should do the job.

Comment: I tried to make a test program that sends a UDP packet, but I don't even manage to get any responses. Unclear whether I send the wrong data or receive with the wrong socket (which would be UDP, port 5355, I think).

Comment: i found an example of how to do UDP broadcasting (and handling the responses) that could be changed to acquire the Samba servers. Answer is updated.

Comment: The gist code works perfectly (I also added code for broadcasting on other interfaces). And it's practically instantaneous. Thanks for digging into this, I wouldn't have figured this out on my own.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would approach it would be to do an IP scan looking for IPs that report an mDNS or SMB name/capability.

Some googling later, it seems that the most suitable command is: `dns-sd -B _smb`

I don't know if this is what apps like LanScan use to do it, but it might give you enough to go on. There seems to be the start of a code trail that could be relevant at: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/65679/15281

Comment: That's promising. The odd thing is that _smb._tcp is a Bonjour concept. It appears that this tool finds the servers that previous were not found by using the Bonjeff or Discovery apps. So it seems that this tool forces a refresh that isn't done by default.

Comment: Also, with my testing, I found that `dns-sb` only finds Linux based smb servers but not those from Windows systems. I also learned by now that the protocol is WINS related, as @karsten pointed out. But I still have not found any method that lists these Windows servers even though the Finder's Network window can show them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed nmap:

```
$ nmap -p 139,445 --script smb-os-discovery [Subnet]/[CIDR]
```

Comment: As I write a public program I cannot depend on 3rd party apps being installed and I rather not bloat my app by including extra tools that may require extra libs even